# How to call models created using H2O in Java code

Tags: java, h2o

How to integrate H2O models with Java code? If you have any reference materials for H2O then please share.

Answer (score 3):

The POJO and MOJO Model Javadoc (start here):

- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/index.html

A list of examples of how to use models:

- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/productionizing.html

A specific self-contained example:

- https://github.com/h2oai/app-consumer-loan

All H2O documentation:

- http://docs.h2o.ai